# Unable to load class with custom static final field

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to add a field that is not base, and does not take into hibernate manager, because it is already final and static.
What am I doing wrong.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "channels")
public class Channel {
    public static final VarType ID = new VarType(Channel.class, "id", Integer.class);
    public static final VarType TITLE = new VarType(Channel.class, "title", String.class);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "chatid")
    private long chatId;
```

Custom field i should add:

```
public class VarType {
    Class<?> cls;
    String name;
    Class<?> type;

    public VarType(Class<?> cls, String name, Class<?> type) {
        this.cls = cls;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
```

Without custom field: ID, TITLE, all work noramlly.
But with:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: com.saderty.db.entities.Channel
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.getPropertyOverriddenByMapperOrMapsId(BinderHelper.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindBasic(AnnotationBinder.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.buildProperty(AnnotationBinder.java:1251)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(EntityBinder.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindEntityClass(EntityBinder.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:556)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:773)
    at com.saderty.HibernateApi.<init>(HibernateApi.java:34)
    at com.saderty.HibernateApi$HibernateApiFactory.build(HibernateApi.java:280)
    at com.saderty.HibernateApi$HibernateApiFactory.build(HibernateApi.java:265)
    at com.saderty.HibernateApi$HibernateApiFactory.Telegram(HibernateApi.java:300)
    at com.saderty.db.DataApi.<clinit>(DataApi.java:25)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.saderty.db.entities.Channel]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderAccessImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:139)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:120)
    ... 26 more
```

Configuration (+annonation on entity classes):

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(annotatedClass);
new HibernateApi(configuration);
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in your configuration

Comment: Already checked...

Comment: Have you provided a mapping file to declare your entity classes. Depending on hibernate/jpa version, it may be needed.